# Is it possible to know the most positive and negative networks of stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I just wanted to know which are the most positive and negative communities. I am defining the method of measuring as, `total votes/total questions` . The site with a higher value of this, shall be more positive and the one with lower value shall be more negative.

Comment: you can use [the data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/326880). I would strongly recommend either considering all posts or limiting votes counted to those cast on questions though. Also, you may or may not wish to break out downvotes separately...

Comment: PeterJ used Data Explorer to rank [the 15 largest sites by +/- voting](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/3963/64871).  You can run his query (which counts votes on all posts since January 1, 2014) for other sites, too.

Comment: Will have to learn to use data explorer!

Comment: What query should I run to get total number of questions? But, from display page stating that stack overflow has 10m questions, and from this [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/327006), stack overflow has only 4.82 upvotes per post.

Comment: While it is as high as 24.433 for [Aviation.SE] (3k questions; 73301 upvotes).

Comment: 3.15 for [SuperUser.SE]

Comment: The fact that deleted questions won't show up in the results is going to greatly skew this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/500806) produces the list for all Stack Exchange communities ranked by their posts/votes ratio.

The per database query counts posttypeid 1 (question) and 2 (answers) from the Posts table. It counts from the Votes table the votetypeid 2 (upmods) and votetypeid 3 (downmod). You can find the detailed data dictionary [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100). The rest is boileplate to run that query per database.

```sql
-- start create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#siteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #siteurl;
GO
create procedure #siteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      -- we have three sites that have borked DNS entries
      set @dbname = (case @dbname
      when 'StackExchange.Audio' then 'StackExchange.Avp'
      when 'StackExchange.Audio.Meta' then 'StackExchange.Avp.Meta'
      when 'StackExchange.Mathoverflow.Meta' then 'net.Mathoverflow.meta'
      else @dbname
      end)
      -- and one of those doesn't want to end with .com
      if @dbname <> 'net.Mathoverflow.meta' 
         set @dbname = 'com.' + @dbname
      exec #recursesiteurl @dbname,  @res OUTPUT
   end
GO
-- create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#recursesiteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #recursesiteurl;
GO
create procedure #recursesiteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      declare @pos integer
      declare @rec nvarchar(250)
       
      set @res = @dbname
      set @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @dbname)
      if (@pos > 0 ) 
      begin
         set @rec = substring(@dbname, @pos+1, len(@dbname))
         exec #recursesiteurl @rec,  @rec output
         set @res = @rec 
                  + '.' 
                  + substring(@dbname, 0, @pos) 
      end
   end;
GO


-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE
                         and ([name] not like '%.Meta' or [name] = 'Stackexchange.meta')

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_stats ( site nvarchar(250)
                            , upvotes int
                            , downvotes int
                            , questions int
                            , answers int
                            );
                            
open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
               declare @url nvarchar(250)
               exec #siteurl ''' + @db_c_name  + ''', @url output
               insert into #all_stats 
               values( @url
               , (select count(*) from votes where votetypeid = 2)
               , (select count(*) from votes where votetypeid = 3)
               , (select count(*) from posts where posttypeid = 1)
               , (select count(*) from posts where posttypeid = 2))
               ;'
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select row_number() over ( order by (upvotes + downvotes) / cast( (questions + answers) as decimal)   desc) as [#]
     , replace(
       replace(
       replace(site,
         '.StackExchange.com',''),
         '.com',''),
         '.net','') as [site]
     , upvotes
     , downvotes
     , questions
     , answers
     , (upvotes + downvotes) / cast( (questions + answers) as decimal) as [pos or neg]
from #all_stats
order by (upvotes + downvotes) / cast( (questions + answers) as decimal)  desc

drop table #all_stats

drop procedure #recursesiteurl
drop procedure #siteurl
```

When run today the first couple of communities look like this:

[image: Rank of communities based on posts/votes]